# python re.findall returning empty list

Tags: python

I have written the code below to grab a string of text from the source code of a website. As denoted, the first findall works just fine while the second returns an empty list. I am trying to get the name (Kendall Easley) from the html underneath the c code.

```
for j in links:
    req = urllib2.Request(j, None, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    page = response.read() #open source code
    org = re.findall(r'(?<=<meta content=").*?(?=" 
    property="og:title")', page)
    print(org) #works
    name = re.findall(r'(?<=ic_only=64" title=").*(?="><img alt=)', page)
    print(name) #prints empty list

<a data-popup="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;profile&quot;}" href="/149855/profile/10525304/display_profile?pic_only=64" title="Kendall Easley"><img alt="Profile Photo" class="user-profile-pic profile_pic_64" height="64" src="https://orgsync.com/assets/icons/accounts/profile_pic_blank_64.gif" width="64" /></a>
```

Comment: Try using https://regex101.com/ to test the regular expression you're trying to use.  If the "findall" isn't returning anything, it's because the regular expression isn't matching.

Comment: I should add that the name varies based on the file

Comment: I matched `Kendall Easley` with that regex, python3.7

Comment: Why are you trying to parse HTML with regexes? Get a parser. BeautifulSoup would make this easier (and more reliable), for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question completely, but this extracts the name out of that html string. Hope it helps

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> html_string = """<a data-popup="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;profile&quot;}"href="/149855/profile/10525304/display_profile?pic_only=64" title="Kendall Easley"><img alt="Profile Photo" class="user-profile-pic profile_pic_64" height="64" src="https://orgsync.com/assets/icons/accounts/profile_pic_blank_64.gif" width="64" /></a>"""
>>> 
>>> name = re.findall(r".*title=\"(\w+\s+\w+)", html_string)
>>> 
>>> name
['Kendall Easley']
```

EDIT* note that I placed triple quotes around the html string

Answer (score -1):

after the first `re.findall()` you have already read the text and the marker is at the end of it.

You have to do a `seek(0)` or something similar for your text (i am reading `txt` files so that works for me) and then `re.findall` again. otherwise it will try to search from the end of the text and of course there is nothing there.

(ps i'm new at python (reading it for 4 weeks))